# What is the length of the polygon in terms of given angles?

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a polygon where the lengths $|AD|$, $|BC|$, and $|CD|$ are known, and $|AD| = |BC|$. Furthermore, $\angle ADC = \alpha$ and $\angle BCD = \beta$.

What is $|AB|$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the known lengths?

[Described Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVw7S.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, we get the length of one of the diagonals using the cosine rule, I will go with $AC$:
$$AC = \sqrt{(DC)^2+(AD)^2-2 (DC) (AD)\cdot \cos\alpha}$$
Then, we get $\angle DCA$ using the sine rule:
$$\frac {AC}{\sin\alpha}=\frac {AD}{\sin(\angle DCA)}$$
Now we can find $\angle ACB$ which is equal to $\beta - m(\angle DCA)$, then we use the cosine rule to get $AB$:
$$AB = \sqrt{(AC)^2+(BC)^2-2 (AC) (BC)\cdot \cos(\angle ACB)}$$